# Creating multiple indexes on the same table to reduce execution time on a large query

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a table with the columns time_stamp and sensor_name (and some other columns that store the sensor data). The table has over a million rows per sensor per day, and we have several months worth of data in there now.

We want to run the following query in a reasonable amount of time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(sensor_name) 
FROM sensor_data 
WHERE time_stamp between '2021-03-30' and '2021-03-31'
```

We already have the following index on the table for optimising the execution of another query. ([General question on optimising a database for a large query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366406/general-question-on-optimising-a-database-for-a-large-query))

```
CREATE INDEX ON sensor_data (sensor_name, time_stamp)
```

Would creating another index with only the sensor_name or only the time_stamp help with my current query's execution time, or is having 2 indexes on the same table a bad idea?

Running on PostgreSQL 10.12 on Aurora serverless.

Comment: For that query I'd try and index on `sensor_data (time_stamp, sensor_name)` so that it can quickly get the records with the desired timestamp and then the distinct names.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: Is having 2 indexes on the same table a bad idea?

Comment: @DrkStr: In general no, it's not a bad idea. Of course indexes come with a (small) penalty for `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s or `DELETE`s one would want to remove completely useless indexes. But as long as indexes support some queries that hit the DB frequently enough or are important enough to be supported, it's absolutely OK to have it, also multiple ones on one table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sensor_name 
FROM sensor_data 
WHERE time_stamp between '2021-03-30' and '2021-03-31'
```

The optimal index is on `sensor_data(time_stamp, sensor_name)`.

Two important notes:

- The order of columns in the index is important.
- The parentheses around `sensor_name` are useless.  The syntactic element is `SELECT DISTINCT`.  `DISTINCT` is not a function.